# Android 10 ACTION_VIEW won't show images outside scoped-storage

Tags: android, android-intent, scoped-storage

I've an image located at `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/xyz.jpg`
And I want to open this image using ACTION_VIEW from my app.
The code I'm using is

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/xyz.jpg");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

My provider paths have

```
<external-path name="external_files" path="." />
```

The above intent shows a picker to select gallery/photos app and system's gallery app gives a blank white screen with error `File format isn't supported or files are corrupted` while photos app just hangs on the loading screen.

So my question is: **Is it possible to directly open a file(outside scoped storage) using ACTION_VIEW? Or Do I have to first copy the file to scoped storage and then show it with ACTION_VIEW?**

Answer: It's not possible to use ACTION_VIEW to open files outside scoped storage. It's also not possible to copy the file since we don't have access to it. So, we can either use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let user choose the file or we can copy the files to scoped storage and keep using ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: "Is it possible to directly open a file(outside scoped storage) using ACTION_VIEW?" -- using the approach that you have shown above, this will only work if you have read access to that file. My guess is that you do not.

Comment: I do have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: And I'm assuming `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` gives read permission to all external storage not just the scoped one.

Comment: Not only Android 10+, unless you have `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on your `<application>` element in the manifest. And that will only work on Android 11 for a few more months -- once you have `targetSdkVersion` set to 30 or higher, that attribute will no longer take effect.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the last comment. I'm targeting `30` and also not using `requestLegacyExternalStorage`. And the code works on Android 7.1 the only other device that I can test with. So I thought it's just Android 10+ that are not supporting ACTION_VIEW outside scoped storage.

Comment: But your first comment suggests that it's possible even on Android 10 and 11 given that I've read permission. If that's correct and I do have the correct permission, then what should be the correct way to debug this one?

Comment: "I'm targeting 30 and also not using requestLegacyExternalStorage" -- then you do not have access to that file on Android 11. "So I thought it's just Android 10+ that are not supporting ACTION_VIEW outside scoped storage" -- you do not have access to that file, so you cannot grant access to it to others via `FileProvider`. "But your first comment suggests that it's possible even on Android 10 and 11 given that I've read permission" -- it should work on 10 with `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`. It will not work on 11, if your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 30 or higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ohh thanks! And How do I get access to the file? Is it the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. If yes, then I've already requested and granted it.

Comment: I can see in the settings' storage permission  that my app is allowed

Comment: "And How do I get access to the file?" -- you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and let the user choose some content from anywhere on their device (and certain cloud storage options).

Comment: Ohh, so that's like opening file browser and giving the user an option to choose anything. I'll see if I can use it, but my use-case is a bit different where I have to open that specific file only.

Comment: Ohh, so that's like opening file browser and giving the user an option to choose anything. I'll see if I can use it, but my use-case is a bit different where I have to open that specific file only.

Comment: So it's kinda true that it's not possible to use `ACTION_VIEW` to open specific files outside scoped storage because I won't have access to them?

Comment: "but my use-case is a bit different where I have to open that specific file only" -- sorry, but that may not be an option. You can also try working with `MediaStore`, since this is an image. "So it's kinda true that it's not possible to use ACTION_VIEW to open specific files outside scoped storage because I won't have access to them?" -- yes. But your original premise was that copying the file would be an option, and you cannot do that either, as you do not have read access to the file.

Comment: Ohh yup, I was under a false illusion that I can open an input stream from file and then copy it. But yeah that copying thing won't work either.
Thanks for the confirmation though, that's exactly what I needed. @CommonsWare.

Comment: Have you tried: new FileInputStream(file) on 10 and 11?

Comment: @blackapps yeah, and they throw EACCES as far as I remember.

Comment: Then the question is: to who belongs that file? How did you put it there? Or which app did it?

Comment: It's the device's camera app.

Comment: Both on an Android 10 and Android 11 emulator my app can open such files. And serve them using ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: @blackapps Really? I was using a physical device till now but I can try Android 10 emulator. 
Just to confirm again, you were able to open the image from camera folder using `ACTION_VIEW`?

Comment: You can read that i said so yes.

Comment: Cool, give me a minute to check this on  Android 10 emulator. i'd be really surprised if this turns out to be a device specific thing.

Comment: @blackapps you're damn right. I tried `Pixel 3 XL API 29` emulator, copied a file to the camera directory and used the above code. And the photos app is able to show the image.

Comment: You said it was a file of the devices Camera app.

Comment: So now I'm really confused. @CommonsWare you said it's not possible and my physical android device also confirms that. But the emulator's photos app is able to show the image.

Comment: @blackapps I even dropped a file from my laptop to the emulator and that too worked.

Comment: Ohh no it doesn't, I think the photos app of emulator is buggy. it did show my image earlier, but after a fresh restart it also hangs now. So @CommonsWare was right that It's not possible to use ACTION_VIEW here.

Comment: I feel alone...!

Comment: @blackapps does it work for you? I think the photos app was able to show the image that the device camera captured but not the ones that I dropped from laptop to emulator.

Comment: On Andoid 10 yes. On Android 11 no.

Comment: @shivampokhriyal, I faced the same issue. As you said, ACTION_VIEW will not work outside scoped storage. However, if you want to copy the file, using MediaStore API, get the URI of the image or video of other apps and copy it to the scoped storage folder i.e your app folder, and then use ACTION_VIEW. This is how I solved the issue. Another solution without copy content would be you can have custom screen in your app similar to ACTION_VIEW behaviour and open it using MediaStore api